# iOS Objective C: Date format returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my `iOS application(Objective C)` I am adding date (29th Nov 2016) in database in following format:

`2016-11-29 04:08:00 PM`

And during displaying it I want to show in following format:

`11/29/2016 04:08:00 PM`

For this I have added formator like

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date1  = [dateFormatter dateFromString: StartDateTime];
//here StartDateTime = 2016-11-29 04:08:00 PM

// Convert to new Date Format with /
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
```

But here `newDate` returns `nil`.

How can I change the date format? Please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: 12-hour format is `hh`

Comment: @vadian ok i am changing it.

Comment: @vadian still returns nil

Comment: Check if date1 is not nil, I think date1 itself is nil.

Comment: The code is supposed to work. Does the string contain additional whitespace or special characters? Or is the space character not `0x20` ?

Comment: @vadian yes date1 is nil. but am passing StartDateTime to it so it should not be nil,right?

Comment: If `date1` is nil there's something wrong with `StartDateTime`

Comment: @User_1191 i just run your code and it's working fine for me. can you print the `StartDateTime` string?

Comment: @Mahesh StartDateTime is not nil

Comment: @User_1191 i know that its not nil but can you print it ?

Comment: @Mahesh yes..its `2016-11-29 04:08:00 PM`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code with below changes:

```
NSString *StartDateTime = @"2016-11-29 04:08:00 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date1  = [dateFormatter dateFromString: StartDateTime];
//here StartDateTime = 2016-11-29 04:08:00 PM

// Convert to new Date Format with /
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date1];
NSLog(@"%@",newDate);
```

Here with in your code I have added a new object of `NSDateFormatter` (For above example `dateFormatter1`) with new allocation and new date formate.
You will get your answer with this way.
Make sure every time that you have to create **new instance** of `NSDateFormatter` every time you want to change the **DateTime formate**.

And even after trying this option, If you don't get your desired result then please try to **run the code in Device, not in Simulator**. Because simulator may not return accurate result all the time especially for date and time